# Prove that L is a positive symmetric operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Let $L$ be the operator :

$$Ly=-(py')' +ry \quad \text{with} \quad p,r>0 \quad \text{on} \quad [a,b]$$

And boundary conditions $$B_a(y)= \alpha y(a)- \beta y'(a)= 0; \quad B_b(y)= \theta y(b) + \delta y'(b)=0 \quad \alpha,\delta,\theta,\beta>0 $$

$1)$Prove that $L$ is a positive symmetric operator(do the calculations).

$2)$Prove that eigenspaces are onedimensional. 
Hint: write the equation as a system and calculate the Wronskian determinant in an appropriate point.

**My attempt:**

So to show that the operator is symmetric we need to show that $$\langle Ly,z\rangle = \langle Az,y\rangle$$

Hence let's start $$\langle Ly,z\rangle = \int( -(py')' +ry)z \, dx= \int -(py')'z + ryz\, dx $$

On the other hand $$\langle Lz,y\rangle = \int( -(pz')' +rz)y \, dx= \int -(pz')'y + ryz\, dx $$

$$ \int ryz\, dx = \int rzy\, dx$$, so we must show

$$ \int -(pz')'y = \int -(py')'z$$

Can anyone help how to proceed from now?

Comment: In proper MathJax or LaTeX usage one writes $\langle Lz,y \rangle = \cdots,$ not $<Lz,y>= \cdots.$ I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: A hint: apply integration by parts to both sides of your last equality, and make use of the boundary conditions.

Comment: And for the second part of the exercise? Could you also give a hint?

Comment: Two solutions, $y_1$ and $y_2$, of $Ly=\lambda y$ are linearly independent if and only if their Wronskian is different from zero for all $x\in[a,b]$. Is that compatible with the boundary conditions?